# Hammerspoon bind "cmd" & "shift" without any other key

Tags: macos, hammerspoon

I want to use hammerspoon to replicate Windows' language switching using `Alt` and `Shift`. For this I want to add a hotkey bind for `command` and `shift`, but all my attempts fail.

I tried:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "shift"}, "", function()
    performAction()
end)
```

and

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "shift", function()
    performAction()
end)
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

philsnow's answer gave me most of the building blocks I needed, here's the code I used to map `cmd` -> `cmd + shift` -> `shift` -> `nothing` to switch between languages like in Windows.
For anyone needing something similar, this code worked for me to switch toggle languages.

```
function same_keys(t1, t2)
    return _same_keys_oneway(t1, t2) and _same_keys_oneway(t2, t1)
    end
    
    function _same_keys_oneway(t1, t2)
    for k, _ in pairs(t1) do
        local found = false
        for j, _ in pairs(t2) do
            if k == j then found = true end
        end
        if found == false then return false end
    end
    return true
end

nMinus1 = {}
nMinus2 = {}
nMinus3 = {}

function tablelength(T)
    local count = 0
    for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
    return count
end

function switchLanguage()
    local lay = hs.keycodes.currentLayout()
    print(lay)
    if lay == "ABC" then
      hs.keycodes.setLayout("Hebrew – PC")
    else
      hs.keycodes.setLayout("ABC")
    end
end

etap = hs.eventtap.new(
   {
      hs.eventtap.event.types.flagsChanged,
   },
   function(ev)
      local flags = ev:getFlags()

      if tablelength(flags) == 0 then
         if (same_keys(nMinus1, {shift = true}) 
                and same_keys(nMinus2, {cmd = true, shift = true})
                and same_keys(nMinus3, {cmd = true})) then
            switchLanguage()
         end
      end
      nMinus3 = nMinus2
      nMinus2 = nMinus1
      nMinus1 = flags
   end
):start()
```

Answer (score 3):

`hs.hotkey` is keystroke-specific and doesn't seem to consider mods going up or down as keystrokes.  `hs.hotkey.bind` eventually [0] calls `hotkey._new` from libhotkey.m (meaning this implementation is baked into the Hammerspoon binary, so changing it would be harder).

On the other hand, `hs.eventtap` lets you see all the modifier changes and react to them.

```
hs.eventtap.new({hs.eventtap.event.types.flagsChanged}, function callback(e) ... end)
```

... will call your callback every time the modifiers change.

I assume you don't want to `performAction` when the modifier sequence goes none -> ctrl -> ctrl+shift -> ctrl+shift+cmd -> shift+cmd, that is, you only want to `performAction` when going from shift -> shift+cmd or cmd -> shift+cmd.  So, you need to remember what the previous set of modifiers was and compare it to the one you see in your callback.

```
etap_last_flags = {}
etap = hs.eventtap.new(
   {
      hs.eventtap.event.types.flagsChanged,
   },
   function(ev)
      local flags = ev:getFlags()

      if same_keys(flags, {cmd = true, shift = true}) then
         if (same_keys(etap_last_flags, {cmd = true}) or
             same_keys(etap_last_flags, {shift = true})) then
            print("do the thing")
            -- performAction()
         end
      end

      etap_last_flags = flags
   end
):start()
```

note that this does `performAction()` right when you hit/keyDown the second modifier key, not when you release/keyUp it.  You could do the latter if you want, by keeping track of more history in `etap_last_flags`.

`ev:getFlags()` returns a table with all the modifiers that are currently set as keys, all with value `true`, so like `{cmd = true, shift = true}`.  You can't just compare those with `==` in lua, so I wrote a janky compare for just this one case:

```
-- This is not a robust table comparison, see
-- http://lua-users.org/wiki/CompareTables if you want that.  This is
-- fine for checking whether two tables of the form {foo = true} and
-- {bar = true} have the same keys.

function same_keys(t1, t2)
   return _same_keys_oneway(t1, t2) and _same_keys_oneway(t2, t1)
end

function _same_keys_oneway(t1, t2)
   for k, _ in pairs(t1) do
      local found = false
      for j, _ in pairs(t2) do
         if k == j then found = true end
      end
      if found == false then return false end
   end
   return true
end
```

Of course another possibility is to use Karabiner-Elements or similar to synthetically emit a plain keystroke like `f18` when shift and cmd are tapped together, and then just `hs.hotkey.bind({{}, 'f18'}, ...)`.

[0] https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/0ccc9d07641a660140d1d2f05b76f682b501a0e8/extensions/hotkey/hotkey.lua#L217

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed response. I ended up changing the code a bit to catch a `cmd -> `cmd + shift` -> `shift` -> `nothing` chain. I added my own answer so the complete code is available for anyone who needs something similar.
Thanks again!